# When should I use 's or of for possession?

Tags: possessives

*I've learned* in school that I should use **'s** *only* for **people** when it means possession. But *after a while*, I realized that is **not** true.

**When** should I *use* **'s** or **of** when the *meaning* is *possession*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the whole, **'s** is used more in speech and colloquial writing than in formal writing, but even for a formal essay it would be an oversimplification to say that **'s** should be restricted to people.

The [Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) website observes that:

> There are some general rules about when to use ’s and when to use of but there are many cases where both are possible.

It then proceeds to set out a few general principles (which are probably still simplifications or generalisations, but not as much so as your teacher's rule):

> We don’t use **’s** when the noun is not a person, animal, country, organisation, etc., or when the noun phrase is very long:
>
> *The name **of** the ship was ‘Wonder Queen’.* (preferred to *The ship’s name was ‘Wonder Queen’.*)
>
> *The house **of** the oldest woman in the village.* (preferred to *The oldest woman in the village’s house.*)
>
> When we are talking about things that belong to us, relationships and characteristics of people, animals, countries, categories, groups or organisations made up of people, we usually use **’s**:
>
> *The men’**s** dressing room is on the left at the end of the corridor.*
>
> *The cat’**s** paw was badly cut.*

Visit the site for further examples.

Answer (score 0):

> Sleep that knits up the ravell'd sleeve **of** care,
>
> The death **of** each **day's** life, sore **labour's** bath,
>
> Balm **of** hurt minds, great **nature's** second course,
>
> Chief nourisher in **life's** feast ...
>
> -- William Shakespeare, *The Tragedy of Macbeth* act2,scene2

There is no reason to think that "**'s**" should only be used for possessives involving people.  In most case's "**'s**" and "**of**" can be used interchangeably.